# Parsing js timestamp in java

Tags: java, parsing, date, time, timestamp

I have a timestamp of the format 1382482802615, which I receive from some js code like this:

```
    new Date().getTime()
```

I need to parse the above timestamp in java. I receive the above data as a string.
I am unable to do the following, which throws a out of range compilation error.

```
    Date date = new Date(1382482802615);
```

But if I do something like this:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

It prints 1383391655609, which contains the same number of digits.

What am I doing wrong?
Or how do I parse something like 1382482802615 into a date in java?

Comment: 1382482802615 is too large to fit into a 32-bit int. You need a long: 1382482802615L.

Comment: *I receive the above data as a string* so do you mean **1382482802615** as string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `L` the value was `int` by default and exceed the limit of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Add `L` to convert int value as long.

```
 Date date = new Date(1382482802615L);
```